# Wordpress theme customizations load incorrectly

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

I'm quite new to wordpress and I made some css customisations to a theme called  WP Bootstrap Starter a few months ago. The website has been perfect but recently it is not loading properly.

Upon refresh - the correct styles load for a split second, then change completely as if they are shrinking, and the font changes. Can anyone point me in the correct direction to start troubleshooting this issue? When I inspect the areas that are changing, a lot of the CSS is striked through including the font family.

Comment: You should be able to tell from the inspection what is overriding that CSS.

Comment: Firstly check your customise code i.e. you haven't missed any } or ; or any other thing.
do share website link so that we can check

Answer (score 0):

inspect that element and check css
or This may have changed with the theme update